# Tyrus client websocket Message handler

Tags: java, websocket, tyrus

***I am experiencing a problem where client does not start in non-debug mode in eclipse. Message do appear in debug mode.***
Please let me know if any one else also facing same issue.

```
    Calling method:
client = ClientManager.createClient();
           ClientEndpointConfig cec = ClientEndpointConfig.Builder.create().build();
           client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.PROXY_URI, "http://192.168.1.1:80");
    session = client.connectToServer(new ClientEndpoint(), cec,  URI.create(url));

Below is the code of ClientEndpoint class:
private static class ClientEndpoint extends Endpoint {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(final Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
            System.out.println("ClientEndpoint: server session opened: "+session);

            session.addMessageHandler(new MessageHandler.Whole<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onMessage(String message) {
                    System.out.println("ClientEndpoint: received message: "+message);
                    if(lastmessage != message)
                    {
                    lastmessage = message;
                    session.getUserProperties().put("Message", lastmessage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
    enter code here

                    session.getUserProperties().put("Message", lastmessage);
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
            try {
                latch.countDown();
                session.close();
                safeDisconnect(session);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

        @Override
        public void onError(Session session, Throwable th)
        {
            try {
                session.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts? Please do let me know the configuration.

Comment: what do you mean by "client does not start"? What is returned from connectToServer?

Comment: anyone got an answer to this?
I have a similar problem, mine connects, but the onMessage never gets called, it gives an java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binary message handler not found